# Find and rename a directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, exec

I am trying to find and rename a directory on a linux system.

the folder name is something like : `thefoldername-23423-431321`

`thefoldername` is consistent but the numbers change every time.

I tried this:

```
find . -type d -name 'thefoldername*' -exec mv {} newfoldername \;
```

The command actually works and rename that directory. But I got an error on terminal saying that there is no such file or directory.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Note that this will also move the renamed directory into whatever dir you ran the find command in. it will no longer be wherever it was found.

Comment: Just to double check, do you want all folders matching that pattern to be renamed to the same thing? What you have would rename `oldName-1-1, oldName-1-2, oldName-1-3, ...` into `newName`. It would not rename it to `newName-1-1, newName-1-2, newName-1-3,...`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ari Thanks, there is only one directory in any given time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a harmless error which you can get rid of with the `-depth` option.

```
find . -depth -type d -name 'thefoldername*' -exec mv {} newfoldername \;
```

Find's normal behavior is to process directories and then recurse into them. Since you've renamed it find complains when it tries to recurse. The `-depth` option tells find to recurse first, then process the directory after.

Comment: How about the case when you would like to preserve the path prefixing the folder that matches (as it could be at a certain depth) and just renaming it? Could you show an example? Thanks!

Comment: @carlspring Perhaps you could ask that in a separate question.

Comment: Done! Please, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027799/rename-directories-matching-pattern .

Answer (score 7):

It's missing the **-execdir** option! As stated in man pages of find:

```
-execdir command {};
```

Like  `-exec`,  but  the  specified  command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find.

`find . -depth -type d -name 'thefoldername*' -execdir mv {} newfoldername \;`

Answer (score 1):

With the previous answer my folders contents are disappeared.
This is my solution. It works well:

`for i in find -type d -name 'oldFolderName';
do
        dirname=$(dirname "$i")
        mv $dirname/oldFolderName $dirname/newFolderName
done`

Comment: To me worked only this way:
for i in `find . -type d -name 'led'`;do mv $(dirname "$i")/oldname $(dirname "$i")/newname; done

Comment: I think "find" should be in quotes, it doesn't work otherwise. Like this: 
`for i in \`find . -type d -name 'myDir'\`;do dirname=$(dirname "$i");mv $dirname/myDir $dirname/_old_myDir; done`

Answer (score 0):

.../ABC -> .../BCD

```
find . -depth -type d -name 'ABC' -execdir mv {} $(dirname $i)/BCD \;
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace 1100 with old_value and 2200 with new_value that you want to replace.

example

```
for i in $(find . -type d -iname '1100');do echo "mv "$i" "$i"__" >> test.txt; sed 's/1100__/2200/g' test.txt > test_1.txt; bash test_1.txt ; rm test*.txt ; done
```

Proof

[user@server test]$ ls -la check/

**drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user    0 Jun  7 12:16 1100**

[user@server test]$ `for i in $(find . -type d -iname '1100');do echo "mv "$i" "$i"__" >> test.txt; sed 's/1100__/2200/g' test.txt > test_1.txt; bash test_1.txt ; rm test*.txt ; done`

[user@server test]$ ls -la check/

**drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user    0 Jun  7 12:16 2200**

here __ in sed is used only to change the name it have no other significance