# Rename multiple directories matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to rename all directories under a basedir which match a name. For example:

In `basedir/`, I have:

```
- foo/bar/blah
- my/bar/foo
- some/bar/foo1
- other/foo/bar
```

I would like to rename all directories matching `bar`, but I would like to preserve the prefix part.

With `find`, I can easily make a list of all the directories like this:

```
find . -name repositoryunit -type d
```

However, how can I use `-exec mv {} ...` (or perhaps combine with another app) so that the prefix is preserved?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
find . -depth -name bar -type d -execdir mv {} baz \;
```

`-execdir` changes directory to the parent before executing the command, so the `mv` here will  be local to each parent directory.

Comment: Be aware, that if in the searched directory is already a directory "baz", the "bar" will be moved into it.

Comment: is there a way to dry-run this command before breaking anything?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Add an `echo`: `find ... -execdir echo mv {} baz \;`