# How to rename multiple directories in bash using a symbol pattern

Tags: bash, directory, find, rename

I am very new to bash so please don't overcomplicate the answer!
I have roughly 200 sub-directories each named similarly to this. (I think they are sub directories. They live within another directory at least.)

```
XMMXCS J083454.8+553420.58
```

I need to bulk rename all of these directories and change the '+' in the directory name to '-'.

To change the names of my directory I have tried:

```
find . -depth -type d -name + -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%/+}/-"' {} \;
```

and

```
find . -name + -type d -execdir mv {} - \
```

However I think this isn't working because + and - aren't letter characters. 
How do I get around this?
Everything I have found online relates to renaming files as opposed to directories, and if anyone knows how to get round this without having to rename them all manually it would be very appreciated.

This previous question I have tried and the syntax doesn't work for me. The folders are all called the same thing after running.
[Rename multiple directories matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027799/rename-multiple-directories-matching-pattern)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR='.'  ## Change to the directory you want.

for SDIR in "$DIR"/*; do
    [[ -d $SDIR ]] || continue           ## Skip if it's not a directory
    BASE=${SDIR##*/}                     ## Gets the base filename (removes directory part)
    NEW_NAME=${BASE//+/-}                ## Creates a new name based from $BASE with + chars changed to -
    echo mv -- "$SDIR" "$DIR/$NEW_NAME"  ## Rename. Remove echo if you think it works the right way already.
done
```

Then run `bash script.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for the script!
Unfortunately this also didn't work for me - nothing changed in the file names again, and printed the old directory name followed by the same old directory name. I've fixed it by doing it the long way and writing a script which just moves every single directory and renames it for each one.

Comment: @LiziSwann Looks like I had a typo. I made a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Your original syntax was pretty close, try something like this

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*+*' -exec bash -c 'mv "${0}" "${0//+/-}"' {} \;
```

Issues

- `-depth` Performs a dfs traversal, but it seems like you only want directories one level deep
- You need to match globs that contain `+`. So `*+*` and not just `+` (quoting is needed with globs so they get processed by find and not the shell)
- With `"${0%/+}/-"` you seem to be mixing up a few syntaxes, `${0//SUBSTRING/TO_REPLACE}` with replace all instances of `SUBSTRING` with `TO_REPLACE`